# Adobe Animate HTML5 alpha fade in

Tags: javascript, html, animation, adobe

I am programming a fade in for the alpha property of a movie clip using a while statement.

It looks like it works, but it runs extremely fast (almost instaneous). Is there any way to set a fade over an interval, or delay the while loop?

```
this.textOverlay.closeButton.addEventListener("click", textFadeOut.bind(this));

function textFadeOut()
{
    this.fertilizerAnimation.gotoAndStop(1);

    while(this.textOverlay.alpha>=0){
        this.textOverlay.alpha-=.01;
        console.log(this.textOverlay.alpha);
        }

}
```

Many thanks--

Comment: don't change DOM in a tight loop like that - you wont see it happening because "rendering" wont take place until your JS code completes

Comment: If you want nice smooth "transitions" ... try using [CSS transitions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Transitions/Using_CSS_transitions)

Answer (score 1):

Edit: As Raphael Rafatpanah pointed out, `requestAnimationFrame()` will not work in a browser. I didn't understand the context when recommending that. `setTimeout()` is non-browser specific and is likely your best bet.

Edit 2: fix scoping error

```
var fadeAmount = 0.01;
var waitTime = 250; // milliseconds == 0.25 seconds
var textOverlay = this.textOverlay;

function textFade () {
    setTimeout(function () {
        if (textOverlay.alpha >= 0) {
            textOverlay.alpha -= fadeAmount;
            textFade();
        }
    }, waitTime);
}

textFade();
```

This will decrement the alpha value by fadeAmount every waitTime milliseconds. Play around with the fadeAmount and waitTime variables to find a rate that you like.

If you *were* in a browser, you could use requestAnimationFrame() and a cycle counter which would tie the animation to the browser's render cycle.

```
var fadeAmount = 0.01;
var n = 24;
var textOverlay = this.textOverlay;

function textFade () {
    requestAnimationFrame(function (cycle) {
        if (textOverlay.alpha >= 0) {
           textOverlay.alpha -= fadeAmount;
        }

        if (cycle % n !== 0) {
            cycle++;
            textFade(cycle);
        }
    });
}

// Call with initial cycle value:
textFade(0);
```

This will decrement the alpha value by fadeAmount every n frames. Play around with the fadeAmount and n variables to find a rate that you like.

See documentation on `requestAnimationFrame()` for more info: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window/requestAnimationFrame

Comment: This would work well in the browser, however OP isn't in a browser environment.

Comment: Thanks @RaphaelRafatpanah, I wasn't aware that the adobe context was outside of a browser. I updated to reflect this using setTimeout as it can be used independently of a browser's render cycle.

Comment: `this` won't refer to what you are expecting within `setTimeout` (or within `requestAnimationFrame`'s callback).

Comment: @RaphaelRafatpanah Thanks again! Updated to reflect the scope change as well.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
this.textOverlay.closeButton.addEventListener("click", textFadeOut.bind(this));

function textFadeOut()
{
  this.fertilizerAnimation.gotoAndStop(1);
  var that = this;
  (function textFadeOut (i) {          
    setTimeout(function () {   
      that.textOverlay.alpha -= 0.01;
      console.log(that.textOverlay.alpha);
      if (--i) textFadeOut(i);
    }, 10) // the animation will last 10ms * 100 iterations (1 second)
  })(100); 

}
```

Answer (score 0):

try this function:

```
function transition_process (fadeAmount,waitTime,faded_obj) {
setTimeout(function () {
    if (faded_obj.alpha >= 0) {
        faded_obj.alpha -= fadeAmount;
        transition_process(fadeAmount,waitTime,faded_obj);
    }
}, waitTime);}
```

and use:

```
var faded_obj = this;
var fadeAmount = 0.025;
var waitTime = 30;
transition_process (fadeAmount,waitTime,faded_obj);
```